# vectorization on DataFrame with date index

Tags: python, dataframe, vectorization

I have a DataFrame like this with dozens of thousand rows :

```
                            A        B
Date                
2020-01-02 09:59:45     -0.007641    1
2020-01-02 10:20:11      0.000211    1
2020-01-02 10:30:27     -0.001294    0
2020-01-02 11:42:54     -0.003468    0
2020-01-02 12:03:22     -0.005559    1
```

The idea is that I would like a column `C` with the last element of the `.cumprod()` of `A + 1` series, every time `B == 1` and beginning at the date of the row.

So here for example, on the second line, as `B == 1`, I take the column A from the date corresponding, `2020-01-02 10:20:11`, with `df.loc['2020-01-02 10:20:11':, 'A']` :

```
                            A        
Date                
2020-01-02 10:20:11      0.000211    
2020-01-02 10:30:27     -0.001294    
2020-01-02 11:42:54     -0.003468    
2020-01-02 12:03:22     -0.005559
```

Then I add 1,

```
                          A
Date
2020-01-02 10:20:11    1.000211
2020-01-02 10:30:27    0.998706
2020-01-02 11:42:54    0.996532
2020-01-02 12:03:22    0.994441
```

I do the `(df.loc['2020-01-02 10:20:11':, 'A']+1).cumprod()`, we obtain :

```
                          A
Date
2020-01-02 10:20:11    1.000211
2020-01-02 10:30:27    0.998916
2020-01-02 11:42:54    0.995452
2020-01-02 12:03:22    0.989919
```

The last value being `0.989919` then in my initial DataFrame it would look like this :

```
                            A        B    C
Date                
2020-01-02 09:59:45     -0.007641    1   a_value
2020-01-02 10:20:11      0.000211    1   0.989919
2020-01-02 10:30:27     -0.001294    0   0
2020-01-02 11:42:54     -0.003468    0   0
2020-01-02 12:03:22     -0.005559    1   another_value
```

So I've discovered vectorization recently and I tried to apply it there. I tried this first to see if i could get the date of each row in column `C` :

```
def last_cumul(date):
    return date

df['C'] = last_cumul(df.index)
```

It worked

```
                            A        B            C
Date                
2020-01-02 09:59:45     -0.007641    1   2020-01-02 09:59:45
2020-01-02 10:20:11      0.000211    1   2020-01-02 10:20:11
2020-01-02 10:30:27     -0.001294    0   2020-01-02 10:30:27
2020-01-02 11:42:54     -0.003468    0   2020-01-02 11:42:54
2020-01-02 12:03:22     -0.005559    1   2020-01-02 12:03:22
```

So i decided to do this :

```
def last_cumul(date):
    return (df.loc[date:, 'A']+1).cumprod()[-1]

df['C'] = last_cumul(df.index)
```

But this time i had the error :

```
TypeError: Cannot convert input [DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-02 09:59:45', '2020-01-02 10:20:11',
               '2020-01-02 10:30:27', '2020-01-02 11:42:54',
               '2020-01-02 12:03:22'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)] of type <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> to Timestamp
```

It is possible to do it using vectorization or i would have to iterate over the DataFrame ?

Thanks !

Comment: brutal vec may still be pretty slow as many of the selections are repeated. If I understand your need correctly, just sort reversely on the date, cumulatively multiply A+1. The result times B and write to C. (Note that will be a simple vec-able calculation). After done, sort back to original order.

Comment: @BingWang why do i need to reverse before the cumprod ? And i need to iterate on each row then ?

Comment: its because the larger the date, the less (A+1) they need to consider, precisely the date rows above it when sorted reversely. I have wrote an answer that assumes you do not need to restart once a B=1 is found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each B=1, the rows with larger dates are selected and A+1 is multipied. While we use cumprod, the order of the rows does not matter since we only choose the last element of cumprod.
With this in mind, we can see the rows needed by a larger date is included in a smaller date. Therefore, in order to save computation, we should find the cumprod of the larger date then reuse it for smaller dates. This is done natually by reverse sorting on Date and apply cumprod on A+1, without any fancy algorithm.

```
df.sort_values(by='Date',ascending=False, inplace=True)
df['C']=(df['A']+1).cumprod()*df['B']
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

This serve two purposes, 1> It reduces computation complexity from O(N2) to O(Nlog(N)) and 2> it keep data slightly more organized for vectorization

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to add some explanation of why and how this solves the problem?